# How to simultanously add several columns to a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this (usually with far more columns and rows):

```
    A   B
0   5  10
1  15   3
```

Now I want to add columns `A_ratio` and `B_ratio` to this dataframe whereby the values there represent `A/(A + B)` and `B/(A + B)`, respectively. So `A_ratio` and `B_ratio` should add up to 1 in each row of the dataframe.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,15], 'B': [10,3]})

for coli in df:
    df[coli + '_ratio'] = df[coli]/df.sum(axis=1)
```

giving me the following result:

```
    A   B   A_ratio   B_ratio
0   5  10  0.333333  0.652174
1  15   3  0.833333  0.159292
```

Clearly, the columns `A_ratio` and `B_ratio` do not add up to 1. While the values in `A_ratio` are correct they are wrong in `B_ratio` since the row sum is changed when `A_ratio` is added.

A workaround could be to copy the dataframe first:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,15], 'B': [10,3]})
df2cl = df2.copy()

for coli in df2:
    df2[coli + '_ratio'] = df2[coli]/df2cl.sum(axis=1)
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
    A   B   A_ratio   B_ratio
0   5  10  0.333333  0.666667
1  15   3  0.833333  0.166667
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this which avoids copying the dataframe?

Comment: Why don't you just change your line to this: `df[coli + '_ratio'] = df[coli]/df[['A','B']].sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: @EdChum: Because I usually have far more columns and do not know their name sin advance.

Comment: updated my answer, just take a copy of the column names before you enter your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call sum each time.

```
 >>%timeit %run multiple_sum.py
   100 loops, best of 3: 6.59 ms per loop

 >>%timeit %run single_sum.py
   100 loops, best of 3: 3.84 ms per loop
```

if you have a big dataframe this is going to be needless overhead.

```
sums = df.sum(axis=1)

for coli in df:
    df[coli + '_ratio'] = df[coli]/sums
```

is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

You can just sub-select from your df so that it only sums those 2 columns:

```
In [195]:
for coli in df:
    df[coli + '_ratio'] = df[coli]/df[['A','B']].sum(axis=1)
df

Out[195]:
    A   B   A_ratio   B_ratio
0   5  10  0.333333  0.666667
1  15   3  0.833333  0.166667
```

You can just take a copy of the column names upfront if you don't want to hardcode them:

```
In [197]:
cols = df.columns
for coli in df:
    df[coli + '_ratio'] = df[coli]/df[cols].sum(axis=1)
df

Out[197]:
    A   B   A_ratio   B_ratio
0   5  10  0.333333  0.666667
1  15   3  0.833333  0.166667
```

Comment: That does the trick, thanks! I upvote for now and accept it later on.